# Update style attribute when ngStyle is updated

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I have a `div` with an `ngStyle` attribute. Initially the `div` looks fine. But when I update a property that is used inside the `ngStyle`attribute, then the `style` tag isn't updated. So the changes aren't reflected to the `div`.

Here's an example of what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/YQIxJYEFWwbxiXr4HBwY?p=preview

Initially the `div` is green. When you click on the button below it then you can see that the `ngStyle` attribute is updated with the `#ff0000` (red) color. But the `style` attribute doesn't get updated.

Is there any way to force angular to update the `style` attribute again?

**Please note:** In my real scenario the div has a lot more `style` properties. And the `div` also has a `<p>` tag which has style properties etc.

I don't want to change the way the `ngStyle` looks right now. I want to know if it's possible to forcefully update the style attribute when I use this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't wrap the `{{bg}}`instead just specify it as `bg`: http://plnkr.co/edit/F1fwgWn48fgZJT1mBiaQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was doing this `ng-style="{{ bgStyle ? bgStyle : ''}}` now works with only `ng-style="bgStyle"`